# Android: Spinners for different screen sizes

Tags: android, spinner

I have a question about Spinner widget in android. All works well except that when I change device with small screen Spinner widgets are overlapped. Is there good practice with managing of sizes of Spinners? In runtime or during design of layout?

Answer (score 0):

[Supporting multiple screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) has some good suggestions on this problem.  Are you using Density-independent pixel (dip) units for all of your views?

If the two screens sizes you are testing with fall into different categories as described there, you could create two layouts, one for each size.